# Does Linux-Kernel Atomic Operations use approaches such as LL/SC?

Tags: c, linux, c++11, linux-kernel, c11

As known, in C++11 and in C11 there are atomic operations with memory_order's:

- C++11: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic
- C11: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic

But linux-kernel developers uses GCC, and because GCC in early versions poorly did optimization of the code written using C11-atomic operations, then linux-kernel developers don't use C11-atomics, but use:

- Linux-Kernel Memory Model: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0124r1.html
- and Linux-Kernel Atomic Operations: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/include/asm/atomic.h

But does Linux-Kernel Atomic Operations use hardware-dependent approaches such as LL/SC (Load-Linked/Store-Condition), which aren't in C11?

Or Linux-kernel-Atomics different from the C11-Atomics only in that the barriers are used separately from atomic operations, and nothing else?

Comment: The source code is publicly available, so I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I think the Linux kernel had its own atomic operations a long time before C11 existed...

Comment: `But does Linux-Kernel Atomic Operations use hardware-dependent approaches` Yes, of course. (check your last link) Porting to new hardware would be impossible if one could only rely on the compiler's atomics. And some assembly will be required anyway.

Comment: joop is absolutely correct. For lock-free atomic read-modify-write operations, the Linux kernel implementations for different architectures can be divided roughly into two categories. One relies on [load-link/store-conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional) or LL/SC, the other on [compare-and-swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) or CAS. There has been (and still is) discussions and a lot of work done on lockless structures and implementing them across these two, in the linux-kernel mailing list (and other kernel sub-lists).